# unable to access a element in different html file

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 html file and one js file.

index.html

```
<h1 class="test">This is a test</h1>
<style src= script.js></script>
```

home.html

```
<h1 class="test1">This is a test</h1>
<style src= script.js></script>
```

script.js

```
let ex = document.querySelector('.test1')
console.log(ex)
```

*//cannot read properties of null.*

**how can access h1 from home.html?**

Comment: you can't. But this is almost certainly a classic [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to upload a picture on index.html then, when i press submit button the picture should appear in home.html

Comment: What do you mean by "appear"? If you mean that any time any user subsequently visits home.html they should see it, then you need server side code to save that image to a database and then have home.html (or rather the server-side script that generates it) read from that same database. Or if you only want it to persist for one user on a particular device, you can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score 1):

> The correct syntax is

```
<script src= script.js></script>
```

> Then you can do -->

```
let ex = document.querySelector('.test1').innerHTML = "Hello World!";
```